# Merge output when using "or" operator in xpath

Tags: python, xpath

I have an xpath expression which makes use of the "|"-operator to select several nodes/divs of an web page.

This is the expression:

```
hxs.select('//div[@class="cat"]/p|//div[@class="entry"]').extract()
```

But when I output the result I get a comma between the output of the first expression

```
//div[@class="cat"]/p
```

and the second

```
//div[@class="entry"]
```

Like:

```
'Lorem ipsum', 'Ipsum Lorem'
```

Is there a way to get rid of the comma?

Like:

```
'Lorem ipsum Ipsum lorem'
```

Or is there perhaps a better way to write xpath expressions which selects Both THIS div AND THIS div.

The rest of the application is written in Python, but I don't think this is relevant to the question. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe `" ".join(hxs.select(...).extract())`

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for helping out!

However, I tried the following: hxs.select('//div[@class="cat"]/p').join(hxs.select('//div[@class="entry"]/text()')).extract(). But it only gave me the error:" AttributeError: 'XPathSelectorList' object has no attribute 'join'". Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: I don't know what you were trying, but that clearly it is not mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.join).

```
" ".join(hxs.select('//div[@class="cat"]/p|//div[@class="entry"]').extract())
```